# Property getters and setters

Tags: swift, properties, compiler-warnings, getter-setter

With this simple class I am getting the compiler *warning*

> Attempting to modify/access `x` within its own setter/getter

and when I use it like this:

```
var p: point = Point()
p.x = 12
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. How can I do this without explicit backing ivars?

```
class Point {

    var x: Int {
        set {
            x = newValue * 2 //Error
        }
        get {
            return x / 2 //Error
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Doing such would also put extra load on the compiler and would consume CPU vigorously. I just did that :| . [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49444) was the error I was creating. ( I was using playground)

Comment: This behavior is confusing, instead of using `set` you want to be using `didSet`. Properties behave differently in Swift than Objective-C or other languages when you implement `set`. See the [answer below from @jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025447/276626) and an [example of `didSet` from @cSquirrel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355948/276626)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Setters and Getters apply to `computed properties`; such properties do not have storage in the instance - the value from the getter is meant to be computed from other instance properties.  In your case, there is no `x` to be assigned.

Explicitly: "How can I do this without explicit backing ivars".  You can't - you'll need *something* to backup the computed property.  Try this:

```
class Point {
  private var _x: Int = 0             // _x -> backingX
  var x: Int {
    set { _x = 2 * newValue }
    get { return _x / 2 }
  }
}
```

Specifically, in the Swift REPL:

```
 15> var pt = Point()
pt: Point = {
  _x = 0
}
 16> pt.x = 10
 17> pt
$R3: Point = {
  _x = 20
}
 18> pt.x
$R4: Int = 10
```

Comment: I was very confused as I skipped through the doc and missed the part that getter and setter are only for computed properties! Thanks for this answer.

Comment: And as I understand you can not set the backing field _x through the x computed property in the constructor since self won't be accessible if _x is not initialised?

Answer (score 119):

You can customize the set value using property observer. To do this use 'didSet' instead of 'set'.

```
class Point {

var x: Int {
    didSet {
        x = x * 2
    }
}
...
```

As for getter ...

```
class Point {

var doubleX: Int {
    get {
        return x / 2
    }
}
...
```

Comment: How could you initialize `x` with a default value in this pattern?

Comment: I see, it would be: `var x: Int = 0 { didSet { ...`.

Answer (score 111):

Setters/getters in Swift are quite different than ObjC. The property becomes a *computed property* which means it does **not** have a backing variable such as `_x` as it would in ObjC.

In the solution code below you can see the `xTimesTwo` does **not** store anything, but simply *computes* the result from `x`.

See [Official docs on computed properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259).

The functionality you want might also be [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262).

What you need is:

```
var x: Int

var xTimesTwo: Int {
    set {
       x = newValue / 2
    }
    get {
        return x * 2
    }
}
```

You can modify other properties within the setter/getters, which is what they are meant for.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am reading in the documentation. I skipped over the property section and it seems there is no way around this, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need another instance variable to "back" the first one if you really want to do this. However, setters are not meant for this purpose you should probably re-think what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: you could use `didSet` which will allow you to change the value immediately after it is set. Nothing for the get though...

Comment: NOTE: If you want to revert the value because it was invalid input, you'd need to set `x` back to `oldValue` in the `didSet`. This change in behavior is very confusing coming from Objective-C properties, thanks!

Answer (score 30):

To elaborate on GoZoner's answer:

Your real issue here is that you are recursively calling your getter.

```
var x:Int
    {
        set
        {
            x = newValue * 2 // This isn't a problem
        }
        get {
            return x / 2 // Here is your real issue, you are recursively calling 
                         // your x property's getter
        }
    }
```

Like the code comment suggests above, you are infinitely calling the x property's getter, which will continue to execute until you get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code (you can see the spinner in the bottom right corner of your Xcode's playground environment).

Consider the example from the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_370):

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
}
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
}
struct AlternativeRect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    var center: Point {
        get {
            let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
            let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
            return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        }
        set {
            origin.x = newValue.x - (size.width / 2)
            origin.y = newValue.y - (size.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the center computed property never modifies or returns itself in the variable's declaration.

Comment: The rule of the thumb is **never** access the property itself from *within* the getter ie `get`. Because that would trigger another `get` which would trigger another . . . Don't even print it. Because printing also requires to 'get' the value before it can print it!

Answer (score 19):

In order to override `setter` and `getter` for swift variables use the below given code

```
var temX : Int? 
var x: Int?{

    set(newX){
       temX = newX
    }

    get{
        return temX
    }
}
```

We need to keep the value of variable in a temporary variable, since trying to access the same variable whose getter/setter is being overridden will result in infinite loops.

We can invoke the setter simply like this

```
x = 10
```

Getter will be invoked on firing below given line of code

```
var newVar = x
```

Answer (score 16):

### Update: Swift 4

In the below class setter and getter is applied to variable `sideLength`

```
class Triangle: {
    var sideLength: Double = 0.0

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) { //initializer method
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSides = 3
    }

    var perimeter: Double {
        get { // getter
            return 3.0 * sideLength
        }
        set(newValue) { //setter
            sideLength = newValue / 4.0
        }
   }
```

### Creating object

```
var triangle = Triangle(sideLength: 3.9, name: "a triangle")
```

### Getter

```
print(triangle.perimeter) // invoking getter
```

### Setter

```
triangle.perimeter = 9.9 // invoking setter
```

Answer (score 8):

You are **recursively** defining `x` with `x`. As if someone asks you how old are you? And you answer "I am twice my age". Which is meaningless.

You must say I am twice John's age or any other variable *but* yourself.

computed variables are always dependent on another variable.

---

The rule of the thumb is **never** access the property itself from *within* the getter ie `get`. Because that would trigger another `get` which would trigger another . . . Don't even print it. Because printing also requires to 'get' the value before it can print it!

```
struct Person{
    var name: String{
        get{
            print(name) // DON'T do this!!!!
            return "as"
        }
        set{
        }
    }
}

let p1 = Person()
```

As that would give the following warning:

> Attempting to access 'name' from within it's own getter.

The error looks vague like this:

[image]

As an alternative you might want to use `didSet`. With `didSet` you'll get a hold to the value that is was set before and just got set to. For more see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355948/5175709).

Answer (score 7):

Try using this:

```
var x:Int!

var xTimesTwo:Int {
    get {
        return x * 2
    }
    set {
        x = newValue / 2
    }
}
```

This is basically Jack Wu's answer, but the difference is that in Jack Wu's answer his x variable is `var x: Int`, in mine, my x variable is like this: `var x: Int!`, so all I did was make it an optional type.

Answer (score 1):

Setters and getters in Swift apply to computed properties/variables.  These properties/variables are not actually stored in memory, but rather computed based on the value of stored properties/variables.

See Apple's Swift documentation on the subject: [Swift Variable Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_512).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a theoretical answer. That can be found [here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/all-about-protocols-in-swift-11a72d6ea354)

> A { get set } property cannot be a constant stored property. It should be a computed property and both get and set should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Swift 5.1**

As of Swift 5.1 you can now get your variable without using **get** keyword. For example:

```
var helloWorld: String {
"Hello World"
}
```

Comment: If I try to change, **helloWorld = "macWorld"** , Cannot assign to value: 'helloWorld' is a get-only property error is showing.

Comment: is thr any possible to assign new values? or no ?

Comment: I do not think it is possible.

Comment: So literaly, var helloWorld: String {
"Hello World"
} and, let helloWorld: String = "Hello World" are same?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I think you have to add *return* keyword

Comment: Maybe I am using swift 5.0 @AtalayAşa