# Encapsulating property transformation/validation

Tags: validation, encapsulation, getter-setter, swift

Imagine I need to write a `Foobar` class with the following partial requirements:

- it needs a read-write property called `someProperty`,
- `SomeProperty` is an Integer with the following constraints:

  - Value must be within `0` to a `100` (inclusively).
  - `42` is an invalid value; If 42 is supplied for `SomeProperty` the next valid value (`43`) will be used/stored.

How would this be accomplished in Swift?

```
class Foobar {
    var someProperty: Int = 0 {
        get {
            return someProperty
        }
        set {
            switch newValue {
            case 42:
                someProperty = 43
            case 0...100:
                someProperty = newValue
            default:
                someProperty = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to [Property getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24025340/1040049) , this is an incorrect use of setters.  If so, how would it be coded?  I don't want every calling entity having to validate Foobar.  Foobar should validate itself (promoting encapsulation).

```
foobarObject.someProperty = 42     // This is wrong, 42 is an invalid value, but how would Foobar enforce this?
println(foobarObject.someProperty) // Should print `43`, because 42 is invalid and it would use the next valid number
```

I've toyed a bit with the idea of having `didSet` or `willSet` do the validation but somehow this seems like a cludge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
class Foobar {
    var someProperty: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            switch self.someProperty {
            case 42:
                self.someProperty = 43
            case 0...100:
                break;
            default:
                self.someProperty = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Switch statement flow, try adding the line:

```
default: 
  self.someProperty = oldValue
```

to preserve old valid state.