# Swift equivalent of lazy Property getter

Tags: objective-c, swift, properties

What is the Swift equivalent of the following expression:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *topView;

- (UIView *)topView {
...
}
```

Is it the following:

```
var topView: UIView {
  get {
    ...
  }
}
```

If the former is true, is there a way to define an external getter?

Comment: `Computed Properties`?

Comment: @PeterM what did you mean?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025340/property-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Based on the title of your question, I would answer that the `Swift equivalent of Property getter` is a `Computed Property` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).  Now it may be that I just don't understand  your actual question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* what you're asking is how to implement something similar to the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *topView

- (UIView *)topView {
    if (_topView == nil) {
        _topView = //...
        // configure _topView...
    }
    return _topView;
}
```

This lazy property getter is easy to achieve in Swift:

```
lazy var topView: UIView = {
    let view = //...
    // configure view...
    return view
}()
```

This results in a read-only variable that is initialised only when first accessed. The Swift code you posted is a computed read-only property which is evaluated every time it is accessed.

Comment: Even in the lazy example you posted I need a helper variable right? Or can I set topView directly?

Comment: @confile No, the lazy example is self contained. The `topView` variable is initialised with the return value of the closure following the '`=`'. If the initialisation can be done on one line, there is no need for the closure, for example: `lazy var topView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)`. I'd strongly recommend reading the ['Properties' chapter of The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: Answer mentions that "This results in a read-only variable that is initialised once when first accessed, and cannot be changed thereafter".  As far as I can tell, a `lazy` variable _can_ be re-assigned after instantiation.

Comment: @sabajt You’re right, thank you. I’m not sure whether this is behaviour that has changed since Swift 1.0, or whether I was just making a false assumption (I feel like I’d tried mutating lazy vars before and failed, but I can’t find evidence that it has ever changed). Either way, I’ve updated the answer.