# Grabbing Google Maps Marker Snippet and Title Value when Marker Info Window Is Tapped Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

so I figured out how to make it so that when i tap a google maps marker info window it takes me to a different view controller but now I also want to pass the currently tapped on markers snippet and title value to that next view controller. I am using the google maps api and programming in swift. The following is the code that I am currently using:

```
func mapView(mapiew: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewUserProfile") as! ViewUserProfile
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
}
```

That pushes to a new view controller, I just need to figure out now how to pass the snippet and title value through that function so that I can use it in the next view controller.

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: you can get marker snippet by **snippet** property. Please refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#a2a8444d762a74f62f6b9a2b4aae2b8d8

Comment: could you please explain it more in code. I am new to swift.

Comment: just write like this let str : String = marker.snippet as! String

Comment: you need to make getter setter properties

Comment: I tried doing this but it still does not work:

Comment: var gettingSnippetStuff: String {
            set {
                currentlyTappedMarkerSnippetValue = (marker.snippet! as String)
            }
            get {
              return "\(currentlyTappedMarkerSnippetValue)"
            
            }
        }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025340/property-getters-and-setters

Comment: that is what I was doing but it does not work

Comment: because it still does not let me use the variable in the next view controller

Comment: you need to create global variable in next view

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: could you maybe show me some code explaining this. I am really sorry for bothering you this much

Comment: Never mind I figured it out thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to transfer data. You must create a new file with a struct:

struct YourVariables {

static var variable = ""

}

You can then go in whatever `view controller` you want to set the variable like this :
YourVariables.variable = "newVariableData"

You then simply go in whatever view controller you want to access the data and set a label.text = YourVariables.variable