# How do you use a setter?

Tags: swift

I was trying to get the grasp of getters and setters in Swift. Here's some code that I wrote.

```
class SomeClass {
 var var1: Int
 var var2: Int{
    get{
        return 7 * var1
    }
    set(newValue){
        newValue * var1
    }
  }
    init(_ var1: Int){
        self.var1 = var1
    }
    
}

var obj = SomeClass(3)
var objComputedProp = obj.var2
print(objComputedProp) //this prints 21

objComputedProp = 14 //I want to change var2's value to 14 (give it a newValue),
                     //so that var2(which is objComputedProp) returns 14*var1 (which would be 42)

print(objComputedProp)//this prints 14
```

I understand that when we write `var obj = SomeClass(3)`, `var1` in the class becomes `3` and the getter returns `7 * var1`. But how do I access the setter? Setting `objComputedProp` to `14` just assigns it 14.

I also tried changing `var1`, but this just prints the same number twice:

```
var obj = SomeClass(3)
var objComputedProp = obj.var2
print(objComputedProp)

obj = SomeClass(5)
print(objComputedProp)
```

Comment: `objComputedProp` is an `Int`, which is a value-type. It doesn't change just because you update `obj`, and it won't change unless you assign another value to it directly. That's irrespective of your setter. But also, you're not actually setting the value to anything in the setter. The idea is that you can set the value inside the setter to other internal properties and hide the implementation from the user of the property. Your implementation doesn't update anything, so setting `obj.var2` doesn't change anything.

Comment: objComputedProp is a Int variable, it has nothing to do with the object `obj` that you have created. If you want to change obj.var2 then work with the object. `obj.var2 = 14`. I would suggest you first learn about objects (instances) , properties and variables so you understand the difference

Comment: In this snippet, `objComputedProp` is just a variable that holds the value it gets from `obj.var2`, it isn't `var2`, which means that assigning a value to `objComputedProp` you're setting the value of the variable itself, you have nothing to do with the `obj.var2` property here, you have to directly assign that 14 to `obj.var2` =) I guess

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025340/property-getters-and-setters#24025548

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning `obj.var2` to `objComputedProp` makes a copy of the value due to value semantics.

The line

```
objComputedProp = 14
```

doesn't call the setter of `var2`.

Apart from that it makes no sense to set the computed variable itself in the setter because it causes an infinite loop.

The setter is supposed to modify the associated variable used in the getter for example

```
set(newValue){
     var1 = var1 * newValue
}
```

---

Another example of a computed variable is for Core Data. The computed property maps a non-supported to a supported type, an array of `String` to a comma separated single `String` and vice versa

```
@NSManaged var string : String

var list : [String] {
    get { return string.components(separatedBy: ",") }
    set { string = newValue.joined(separator: ",") }
}
```